# Stop Words from python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a text file where I am counting the sum of lines, sum of characters and sum of words. How can I clean the data by removing stop words such as (the, for, a) using string.replace()

I have the codes below as of now.

Ex. if the text file contains the line:

```
"The only words to count are Buttons and Shares for this text"
```

It should output:

```
1 Buttons
1 Shares
1 words
1 only
1 text
```

Although my code does not output the stop words that I have blacklisted but it also removes the stop words if its inside any other words. Below is what my code outputs.

```
1 Butns (this is a problem)
1 Shs (this is a problem)
1 words
1 only
1 text
```

Below is the code I have as of now.

```
# Open the input file
fname = open('2013_honda_accord.txt', 'r').read()

# COUNT CHARACTERS
num_chars = len(fname)

# COUNT LINES 
num_lines = fname.count('\n')

#COUNT WORDS
fname = fname.lower() # convert the text to lower first

# Remove Stop words 
blacklist = ["the", "to", "are", "and", "for", "this" ]  # Blacklist of words to be filtered out
for word in blacklist:
   fname = fname.replace(word, "")

# Removing special characters from the word count
get_alphabetical_characters = lambda word: "".join([char if char in 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890-' else '' for char in word])
words = list(map(get_alphabetical_characters, fname.split()))

d = {}
for w in words:
    # if the word is repeated - start count
    if w in d:    
       d[w] += 1
    # if the word is only used once then give it a count of 1
    else:
       d[w] = 1

# Add the sum of all the repeated words 
num_words = sum(d[w] for w in d)

lst = [(d[w], w) for w in d]
# sort the list of words in alpha for the same count 
lst.sort()
# list word count from greatest to lowest (will also show the sort in reserve order Z-A)
lst.reverse()

# output the total number of characters
print('Your input file has characters = ' + str(num_chars))
# output the total number of lines
print('Your input file has num_lines = ' + str(num_lines))
# output the total number of words
print('Your input file has num_words = ' + str(num_words))

print('\n The 30 most frequent words are \n')

# print the number of words as a count from the text file with the sum of each word used within the text
i = 1
for count, word in lst[:10000]:
print('%2s.  %4s %s' % (i, count, word))
i += 1
```

Thanks

Comment: You should probably do the stop word processing after you have split the text into individual words. Then you can easily check for whole word matches only.

Comment: There are libraries that have premade stopword lists and will remove them for you (NLTK, sklearn) - are you set on building this yourself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you don't need punctuation for your analysis, you can do something like this -

```
punctuation_list = ['?',',','.'] # non exhaustive

for punctuation in punctuation_list:
   fname = fname.replace(punctuation, "")

blacklist = ["the", "to", "are", "and", "for", "this" ]  

for word in blacklist:
   fname = fname.replace(" "+word+" ", " ") #replace StopWord preceded by a space and followed by a space with a space
```

Comment: This seems to be have working the best! Thanks for the assistance!

Answer (score 0):

You are removing "to", "are", and replacing them.

```
# Remove Stop words 
blacklist = ["the", "to", "are", "and", "for", "this" ]  
# Blacklist of words to be filtered out
for word in blacklist:
   fname = fname.replace(word, "")
```

Comment: so what is the suggestion here?

Answer (score 0):

Move the filtering out of stopwords to when you've created `d`, the dictionary mapping words to counts. Adding a single line there - `if w not in blacklist:` - skipping words contained in the blacklist will remove stopwords without changing the other words.

```
#COUNT WORDS
fname = fname.lower() # convert the text to lower first

# Removing special characters from the word count
get_alphabetical_characters = lambda word: "".join([char if char in 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890-' else '' for char in word])
words = list(map(get_alphabetical_characters, fname.split()))

# Remove Stop words 
blacklist = ["the", "to", "are", "and", "for", "this" ]  # Blacklist of words to be filtered out

d = {}
for w in words:
  # Do not count words in the blacklist
  if w not in blacklist:
    # if the word is repeated - start count
    if w in d:    
      d[w] += 1
    # if the word is only used once then give it a count of 1
    else:
      d[w] = 1
```